# Implementation of soap client in node.js with easy-soap

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-services, soap

Here is my code, every thing is working except the call soap method 
which returns an error, please help :)

```
 "use strict";

    var easysoap = require('easysoap');

    // define soap params
    var params = {
        host: 'www.privateqa.invoice4u.co.il',
        path: '/Services/MeshulamService.svc',
        wsdl: '/Services/MeshulamService.svc?singleWsdl',
    }
/*
 * create the client
 */"
var soapClient = easysoap.createClient(params);
```

> ```
> /*
>  * get all available functions
>  */
> ```

```
soapClient.getAllFunctions()
    .then((functionArray) => { console.log(functionArray); })
    .catch((err) => { throw new Error(err); });
```

> ```
> /*
>  * get the method params by given methodName
>  */
> ```

```
soapClient.getMethodParamsByName('ProccessRequest')
    .then((methodParams) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(methodParams.request));
        // console.log(JSON.stringify(methodParams.response));
        return methodParams;
    })
    .catch((err) => { 

        console.log(err); });
```

> /*
>        * call soap method
>        */

```
            soapClient.call({
                method    : 'ProccessRequest',
                attributes: {
                    xmlns: "https://privateqa.invoice4u.co.il/"
                },
                params: {
                    'UserEmail'   : 'test@test.com',
                    'UserPassword': '123456',
                    'FullName': 'idan tabachnik',
                    'Phone': '0525410849',
                    'Sum': 10.00,
                    'PaymentsNum': 1,
                    'Type': 1,
                    'ReturnUrl': 'mako.co.il'
                }
}).then((callResponse) => {
    debugger;
    console.log(callResponse.data);    // response data as json
    // console.log(callResponse.body);    // response body
    // console.log(callResponse.header);  //response header
 }).catch((err) => { throw new Error(err); });
```

the error i get "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection"

> http://private.invoice4u.co.il/Services/LoginService.svc

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have already solved the problem. If not check your last line of the code. You are throwing the error, but you did  not write anything to catch that error. That's why it's showing the unhandled promise rejection error. You can either print the error or write some method to catch the error in some other place.

Here's a [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error#Throwing_a_generic_error) to help you with the throwing and catching error